# OAuth-php behavior differs from a local version to a domain.com version

Tags: php, http, post, oauth

I've been developing locally and exposing them with OAuth (oauth-php framework). Everything works perfectly fine locally on my laptop but when I deploy everything on my server it doesn't work anymore I get the following error when I'm trying to get a request_token:

```
Can't verify request, missing oauth_consumer_key or oauth_token
```

I've be investigating why it doesn't behave the same and the only clue that I found is in the log of OAuth: it looks like the oauth-php framework doesn't fetch properly the parameters in my POST Requests.

I have the same version of PHP on my server and on my local environment. I don't know what else could be affecting the oauth-php framework.

What can I do to find the problem? I don't know where to look...

Thanks!

Martin

Comment: Not sure if it helps, since this guy never got an answer, but here's a recent post complaining of the same thing on another (perhaps dependent) project: https://github.com/jmathai/twitter-async/issues/closed#issue/98

Comment: Thanks but I've already seen that post. I contacted the man complaining about that issue but he didn't answer me yet...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that the Authorize header was stripped from the request, I renamed it on the client and server side and everything is working great.